# Removing all but a few specific elements from a list in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, getelementsbyclassname

Let's say I have a list of elements `a = document.getElementsByTag('li')`. I want to delete every element in that list except for those at positions `keep = [3, 5, 8]`. Ordinarily, this could easily be done with a for loop, and just making sure to skip the good positions.

```js
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (!keep.includes(i)) {
    a[i].remove();
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, when removing elements from `a`, that dynamically changes `a`, and the positions/indexes of everything get shifted. If I wanted to, it's not too hard to account for this shifting. But is there a a more straight-forward / elegant method to do this task? I'd like to learn a more proper method before I just hack things to make it work.

For the record, the new solution I was thinking of was something like

```js
shift = 0;
len = a.length;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (!keep.includes(i)) {
    a[i-shift].remove();
    shift++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not grab that few elements and add them to a new array?

Comment: You are not obligated to navigate the loop start to end.  If you count decreasing i from the end, remove(i) doesnt create any problem.

Comment: filter is a good idea, and so is iterating from index length-1 down to 0.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use `filter` instead of looping. I find it quite idiomatic in javascript:

```js
a = a.filter(x => keep.includes(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the indexing of the keep values in an array then instead of removing the other values, You can replace them with `undefined`.

Here you go **:**

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const keep = [3, 5, 8];

a.forEach((num, index) => {
  if (!keep.includes(index)) {
    a[index] = undefined
  }
});

console.log(a);
```